# How do I disable the default "click-to-dismiss" behaviour of QSplashScreen?

Tags: python, pyside2

I am using a QSplashScreen to get some desired behaviour for free: image display, centering, easy framelessness.

The problem is that for my use case, I do not want clicks on the image to dismiss the screen.

I have tried overriding eventFilter as so many c++ posts about this very behaviour suggest, but in PySide 2.x.x / Qt5 that method is never called.

```
class MySplashScreen(QtWidgets.QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self, my_pixmap):
        super(MySplashScreen, self).
            __init__(my_pixmap, QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint |
                            QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        print("never called")
```

Is there something else simple that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my purposes, all I had to do was override mousePressEvent() and pass.

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    # disable default "click-to-dismiss" behaviour
    pass
```

This prevented clicks from dismissing the screen, but did not affect mouse events on UI elements I laid out over top of the splash screen, so it ticked all my boxes.

Comment: Exactly, in the mousePressEvent method the hide method is called https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qsplashscreen.cpp?h=dev#n166

Comment: permanent link for the easily confused: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/ca254a0937d58e573a0e2b210590de2a02326e5f/src/widgets/widgets/qsplashscreen.cpp#L130-L133